# u-boot compilation error

Tags: compiling, u-boot

I am trying to build u-boot and getting these error

```
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE G0
Building U-boot
make -C u-boot ARCH=arm fio-om3xxx_config
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mrigendra/GingerBread_2_3_4_FIO/u-boot'
Configuring for fio-om3xxx board...
rm: cannot remove `asm': Is a directory
make[1]: *** [fio-om3xxx_config] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mrigendra/GingerBread_2_3_4_FIO/u-boot'
make: *** [uboot] Error 2
```

i don't know why it wants to remove asm directory.
do anybody have idea from where i should start ..

Answer (score -1):

Try running this first:

```
make -C u-boot distclean
```

That should remove the 'asm' directory, which is likely at include/asm.

You could also manually remove it, I suppose:

```
rm -rf include/asm
```

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: It might actually do the trick but I don't have a system to test it on.  Adding some details to your answer would make it more proper.